# Avoid naming strategy for a single field in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a field anotated with @Column()

```
@Column(name = "camelCase")
private Long camelCase;
```

the field effectively is named that way in my DB, but hibernate is changing the "camelCase" by camel_case behind the scenes, this is is a good behavior for the rest of the fields but not for this one (in my case)

do you know a way to avoid this behavior for just a field ?

PS: I am using Hibernate 4.3.11.Final

Comment: What hibernate version?

Comment: Hibernate 4.3.11.Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solution was just to use the name in lower case.

```
@Column(name = "camelcase")
private Long camelCase;
```

As I mention on a comment I am not sure if this will be platform dependent but for now this work for me, any further improvement or comment about this will be always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding Hibernate uses naming-stragies to handle the column-names in the database. A default behaviour of these strategy is to replace upper case letters by underscore and lower-letter so "camelCase" becomes "camel_case".
Have you tried to implement your own Naming-Strategy? Or at least extend one?

You can find a good example here: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/implementing-a-custom-namingstrategy-with-hibernate/

Comment: Thank you @christoph-tobias-schenke, that will be my last resort, because it implies use the same naming-strategy for all the fields and all the classes, and I just wanted to handle this single case, I've tried with the name in lower case "camelcase" and it actually works, but I fear this behavior will be platform dependent, you have an idea of this ?